# Why i'm can start container with volumes param

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

My problem is that when I start the images without specifying the volumes parameter, everything is fine. But when I specify the container cannot start with the following error ...

This is my docker-compose:

```
version: '3.7'
# Use root/example as user/password credentials
services:

  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123zemtsov321
    volumes:
      - ./docker/database/mysql01:/var/lib/mysql

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 6080:8080

db_1       | mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
db_1       | 2019-09-05T10:16:32.860733Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011070] [Server] 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent) is the default. Consider not using this option as it' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
db_1       | 2019-09-05T10:16:32.861130Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.17) starting as process 1
db_1       | 2019-09-05T10:16:34.628973Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010735] [Server] Could not open the mysql.plugin table. Please perform the MySQL upgrade procedure.
db_1       | 2019-09-05T10:16:34.737017Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010015] [Repl] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
db_1       | 2019-09-05T10:16:34.788763Z 0 [Warning] [MY-000054] [Server] World-writable config file './auto.cnf' is ignored.
db_1       | 2019-09-05T10:16:34.789050Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010107] [Server] World-writable config file './auto.cnf' has been removed.
db_1       | 2019-09-05T10:16:34.789371Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010075] [Server] No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating a new UUID: 3d261de8-cfc6-11e9-a284-0242ac120003.
db_1       | 2019-09-05T10:16:34.922344Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010015] [Repl] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
db_1       | 2019-09-05T10:16:34.958036Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010069] [Server] Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library error: SSL context is not usable without certificate and private key
db_1       | 2019-09-05T10:16:34.958975Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010284] [Server] RSA public key file not found: /var/lib/mysql//public_key.pem. Some authentication plugins will not work.
db_1       | 2019-09-05T10:16:34.959371Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010284] [Server] RSA public key file not found: /var/lib/mysql//public_key.pem. Some authentication plugins will not work.
db_1       | 2019-09-05T10:16:34.964792Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
db_1       | 2019-09-05T10:16:34.965651Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010441] [Server] Failed to open optimizer cost constant tables
db_1       | 2019-09-05T10:16:34.966395Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013129] [Server] A message intended for a client cannot be sent there as no client-session is attached. Therefore, we're sending the information to the error-log instead: MY-001146 - Table 'mysql.component' doesn't exist
db_1       | 2019-09-05T10:16:34.966438Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013129] [Server] A message intended for a client cannot be sent there as no client-session is attached. Therefore, we're sending the information to the error-log instead: MY-003543 - The mysql.component table is missing or has an incorrect definition.
db_1       | 2019-09-05T10:16:34.968178Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010326] [Server] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist
db_1       | 2019-09-05T10:16:34.968332Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010952] [Server] The privilege system failed to initialize correctly. For complete instructions on how to upgrade MySQL to a new version please see the 'Upgrading MySQL' section from the MySQL manual.
db_1       | 2019-09-05T10:16:34.969207Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
db_1       | 2019-09-05T10:16:35.815514Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.17)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
work_db_1 exited with code 1
```

Why i'm get this is errors?????

Comment: What is in `./docker/database/mysql01`? Did you copy this from another mysql instance (that wasn't created with this docker config)? I would try to delete the contents and see if you get the same error on startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it might be caused by whatever's currently in `./docker/database/mysql01` when you start it up. I'd start troubleshooting by mounting the to a *different* location on your filesystem (to see if a fresh start resolves the issue), or dig into your existing contents to root out what's tripping it up. This post (while rather old) looks like it solves something similar to the errors you're seeing in your situation:

https://ma.ttias.be/mysql-table-mysql-plugin-doesnt-exist-after-mysql-upgrade/